# Метод Delete node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Подскажите пожалуйста почему данный код не убирает элемент из массива.

```
app.delete('/api/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
  NOTES = NOTES.filter((item) => item.id !== req.params.id);
  notesCounter = NOTES.length;
  res.status(200).json({ message: `note ${req.params.id} was deleted` });
});
```

Вот если что функция которая вызывается при нажатии на кнопу Delete:

```
async function deleteNote(id) {
  const res = await fetch(`/api/notes/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
  });
  getNotes();
}
```

Запрос выполняется и выдает ответ , но массив остается неизменным.
Функция `getNotes()` это Get запрос и выполняется корректно.

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Метод не работал поскольку, `req.params.id` это строка.

Добавил унарный оператор и заработало:

```
NOTES = NOTES.filter((item) => item.id !== +req.params.id);
```